# Is This a run on?

Tags: sentence-construction

Sentence in question:

> "Through his work with pea plants, the Austrian scientist Gregor Mendel arrived at his theory of heredity, a discovery that was remarkable."

I think this sentence is a run-on as the discovery is another subject that is not connected to the previous clause witha conjunction...

I think the sentence should be corrected as

> "Through his work with pea plants, the Austrian scientist Gregor Mendel arrived at his theory of heredity, which was remarkable and a great discovery".

Am I correct?

Comment: Do you have a source this came from?

Comment: SAT exam practice from Princeton rev.

Comment: I see. Can a theory be a discovery? Are you saying its not?

Comment: yes, a theory can be a discovery. I'm concerned that three subjects are present in this sentence. One subject is of dependent clause, another is independent, and the last is another independent clause.

Comment: On the first glance it looks like an apposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A discovery that was remarkable* is a noun phrase—a noun with its determiner *a* and a modifying relative clause *that was remarkable*.

This noun phrase is set in [*apposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) to the noun phrase *his theory of heredity*, providing a further comment on it. There is no conjunction with such appositives: they are merely set next to each other&that is what ‘apposition’ means, a ‘placing to’.

This is merely a longer version of a construction you are probably familiar with:

> ... Elizabeth II, Queen of England ...
>   ... John, my brother ...
>   ... *Hamlet*, Shakespeare's most famous work ...

Comment: Is the following correct? ""Through his work with pea plants, the Austrian scientist Gregor Mendel arrived at his theory of heredity, a discovery that was remarkable.""

Comment: @Ben Yes, perfectly grammatical. I apologize for substituting relative *which* for relative *that*; that is my own practice.

Comment: That's my practice also. I see how the "sentence in question" isn't a run-on. the **"that"** in the last part of the sentence indicates a dependent clause. I forgot that "that" indicates a dependent clause.